# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined on POST HTTP Call - Angular [8]

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular8

I'm trying to Post data to rest API. I'm using Postman for my rest API.
Getting Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined on POST HTTP Call in console log:

[image: Console Log Error]

My rest API: "dradiobeats.x10host.com/api/areas"

**userService.ts:**

```js
import { Injectable, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
import { userArray } from "./users.model";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Authorization:
      "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6ImYyOTc3OTBmODc3ODlhYzg3MGE2ZmU3YTY0YzY2YmIwOGU4M2Q0ZmQzY2IyNmNiNWU3NDEzMTFmZjExMDk4NTA5NWUzN2IxN2I5YmI2YmFjIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIyIiwianRpIjoiZjI5Nzc5MGY4Nzc4OWFjODcwYTZmZTdhNjRjNjZiYjA4ZTgzZDRmZDNjYjI2Y2I1ZTc0MTMxMWZmMTEwOTg1MDk1ZTM3YjE3YjliYjZiYWMiLCJpYXQiOjE1NzU4NzM4MzksIm5iZiI6MTU3NTg3MzgzOSwiZXhwIjoxNjA3NDk2MjM5LCJzdWIiOiIyIiwic2NvcGVzIjpbXX0.J3nMXcPpqlRVvIRkrVAMblSUwdlXFmrkn9SPD2WE1DwdiqAMdhay8zAeD550ta9qWiNxHOKMAWF8t3H9cIgItaB9ZX2CxoxzS5P1nJFzit8qxiB-gzJL3mpybrnLtrKGjxsM5i_lBvdJsnhWzi15jKWIu-RNxUYPnXCjuxnXYEiyoJg17hsYUh4910VfFWx4R3WvH7WOvczF53IDKyX5fSTt4WSJUqciuNepkO6Klc8sj_yPmDPQltUjUXSSplkOQ8sL5uHk7PmzSjIfoR8RC0A-YQqI9mbZMTyJ0IyKoAHvRHF8q1cW5qfUmLXTgxcCTmFPqXqIlcAoOoJMCxke5fl0PuK0rgU7dxouATk_3B6cio7-7Zgps0iopDpk2nm-o40mjSiOUGb2kyKckYN09orYuan5wEd1KJ873ejKEgBWOhJu4gQFps8M9VoDXncAqMxeBqbUY1UZENx_n6uduQ_SAY4rgIUFCixfNc5Y_-HLDa108u4-z3APGbdxrhEdZXyHz9xQTaLrWcU_iCJ5g_ObT5VGZHtawZbfOYm2ZZpjPiCZpXunhrsbAcHBX64akWcehmT2gUJqPsxvaObKN3nayML1NHtdZGgAHUE89clhIH610Fod0C_jMTqpU7IkY9aSU781HsQVlHNw3qGbTinWfYPDBG0Lkp9NnmRe9BU",
    Accept: "application/json"
  })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class UsersService {
  users$: userArray[];
  apiUrl = "http://dradiobeats.x10host.com/api/areas";
  delUrl = "http://dradiobeats.x10host.com/api/areas";

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}

  getUsers() {
    return this._http.get<userArray[]>(this.apiUrl);
  }

  deleteUser(id: userArray): Observable<userArray> {
    const url = `${this.apiUrl}/${id}`;
    console.log();
    return this._http.delete<userArray>(url, httpOptions);
  }
  onSubmit(users$: userArray): Observable<userArray> {
    console.log(users$);
    this._http.post<userArray>(this.apiUrl, users$, httpOptions);
  }
}
```

**add-post.component.ts:**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { UsersService } from "src/app/users.service";
import { userArray } from "src/app/users.model";

@Component({
  selector: "app-add-posts",
  templateUrl: "./add-posts.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./add-posts.component.css"]
})
export class AddPostsComponent implements OnInit {
  name: string;
  description: string;
  domain: string;
  picture: string;
  id: number = 29;
  constructor(private userService: UsersService) {}
  users: userArray[];
  ngOnInit() {}

  onSubmit() {
    const users$ = {
      name: this.name,
      description: this.description,
      domain: this.domain,
      picture: this.picture
    };
    this.userService.onSubmit(users$).subscribe();
  }
}
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **return** the http call observable

Try:

```
onSubmit(users$: userArray): Observable<userArray> {
  console.log(users$);
  return this._http.post<userArray>(this.apiUrl, users$, httpOptions);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As onSubmit() has an Observable signature, it must return an observable. You must change your function to 'return this.http.post ...'

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to return, As only observable can be subscribe

```
import { Injectable, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
import { userArray } from "./users.model";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Authorization:
      "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6ImYyOTc3OTBmODc3ODlhYzg3MGE2ZmU3YTY0YzY2YmIwOGU4M2Q0ZmQzY2IyNmNiNWU3NDEzMTFmZjExMDk4NTA5NWUzN2IxN2I5YmI2YmFjIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIyIiwianRpIjoiZjI5Nzc5MGY4Nzc4OWFjODcwYTZmZTdhNjRjNjZiYjA4ZTgzZDRmZDNjYjI2Y2I1ZTc0MTMxMWZmMTEwOTg1MDk1ZTM3YjE3YjliYjZiYWMiLCJpYXQiOjE1NzU4NzM4MzksIm5iZiI6MTU3NTg3MzgzOSwiZXhwIjoxNjA3NDk2MjM5LCJzdWIiOiIyIiwic2NvcGVzIjpbXX0.J3nMXcPpqlRVvIRkrVAMblSUwdlXFmrkn9SPD2WE1DwdiqAMdhay8zAeD550ta9qWiNxHOKMAWF8t3H9cIgItaB9ZX2CxoxzS5P1nJFzit8qxiB-gzJL3mpybrnLtrKGjxsM5i_lBvdJsnhWzi15jKWIu-RNxUYPnXCjuxnXYEiyoJg17hsYUh4910VfFWx4R3WvH7WOvczF53IDKyX5fSTt4WSJUqciuNepkO6Klc8sj_yPmDPQltUjUXSSplkOQ8sL5uHk7PmzSjIfoR8RC0A-YQqI9mbZMTyJ0IyKoAHvRHF8q1cW5qfUmLXTgxcCTmFPqXqIlcAoOoJMCxke5fl0PuK0rgU7dxouATk_3B6cio7-7Zgps0iopDpk2nm-o40mjSiOUGb2kyKckYN09orYuan5wEd1KJ873ejKEgBWOhJu4gQFps8M9VoDXncAqMxeBqbUY1UZENx_n6uduQ_SAY4rgIUFCixfNc5Y_-HLDa108u4-z3APGbdxrhEdZXyHz9xQTaLrWcU_iCJ5g_ObT5VGZHtawZbfOYm2ZZpjPiCZpXunhrsbAcHBX64akWcehmT2gUJqPsxvaObKN3nayML1NHtdZGgAHUE89clhIH610Fod0C_jMTqpU7IkY9aSU781HsQVlHNw3qGbTinWfYPDBG0Lkp9NnmRe9BU",
    Accept: "application/json"
  })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class UsersService {
  users$: userArray[];
  apiUrl = "http://dradiobeats.x10host.com/api/areas";
  delUrl = "http://dradiobeats.x10host.com/api/areas";

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}

  getUsers() {
    return this._http.get<userArray[]>(this.apiUrl);
  }

  deleteUser(id: userArray): Observable<userArray> {
    const url = `${this.apiUrl}/${id}`;
    console.log();
    return this._http.delete<userArray>(url, httpOptions);
  }
  onSubmit(users$: userArray): Observable<userArray> {
    console.log(users$);
   return this._http.post<userArray>(this.apiUrl, users$, httpOptions);
  }
}
```